# Padding the JSON object sent on save() with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ruby, backbone.js

I'm trying to send an object from Backbone.js to my Rails backend. Currently when I call `save()` on my model, it sends this to the server:

```
{"program_id":1,"issuer_id":4}
```

But Rails is expecting it in the following format:

```
{"program_issuer_link":{"program_id":1,"issuer_id":4}}
```

Is there any way I can do this encapsulation to the JSON object that gets sent from Backbone.js to Rails when I call `save()` on my model? I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are using the `backbone-rails` gem, then you can do it like this.

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
   paramRoot: 'user'
});
```

You can also override the `toJSON` method like this

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  toJSON: function(){
    return {user: _.clone(this.attributes)}
  },
});
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks Orlando. I used the second method and it worked beautifully.

Comment: @orlando Are you sure the first one is just available with backbone-rails?

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu try it and see if it works, its a monkey patch they do for rails (you know, cuz rails expects JSON with root node, is easy to replicate if you want it on Backbone.js, i'll add info on how to do it to the answer.

Comment: yeah, I haven't found anything on the Backbone docs. Thanks for the response and you don't have to provide info on how to do it :) but it sure would make your answer more valuable